# Magento 2 States are not Loading while Selecting Country on New Account Create Page

Tags: magento2, customer-registration

I have customize the New account Create page(Registration page) in Magento 2.3

And Also enabled the option country and state. But when selection country state is not loading.

I have checked the `admin->General->Country Option->state Options` and set the **state is required** for all country, but still it is not working.

Is there is any other settings that will require to load the state option.

Please share your idea and help me to resolve that issue.

Comment: issue has been resolved,it was just JS conflict issue.